# Android - ArrayAdapter: set TextView to value from SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

**What I want to accomplish:**

I want one TextView per row of a ListView to be dynamically set (its display text) to the value from a SQLite database.

**What I tried:**

Inside `getView()`, I assigned the said TextView via `findViewById()` to a global variable. Then I assigned the value `position` (from the parameter of `getView()`) to my global variable `mListRowPosition`. After this, I execute my AsyncTask sub-class via `new AttemptGetCustomerInfo().execute()`.

My AsyncTask sub-class gets the `SQLiteDatabase` from my `DatabaseHelper`. With the `mListRowPosition` it receives the `customer_id` from the method `getCustomerID()` of the Service object inside the `ArrayList<Service>` dataset.

Together with the `customer_id`, it builds a SQL query to get the shortname of the customer. After querying, it gets the String `shortname` from the Cursor. I then `setText(shortname)` the global TextView from before (inside `getView()`).

**The problems with that:**

This 'kind of works' at some point, but it seems to be so slow that only the last (almost every time) has a value set as its text. Sometimes it also gets it wrong.

After debug-logging I saw that `getView()` gets called a lot faster than the AsyncTask is even finished (this makes sense, but it destroys my solution for my problem).

Also interesting: My debug log tells me that `getView()` gets called more often then there are data entries inside the ArrayList. If there are 5 entries, it will call `getView()` about 15 to 20 times. Why?

**The code behind that:**

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Service> {

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Service service = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.listview_row, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView quantity = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.QUANTITY_CELL);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.DESCRIPTION_CELL);
        Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_DELETE);
        customerView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CUSTOMER_VIEW);
        mListRowPosition = position;
        Log.d("ServiceAdapter", "getView changed mListRowPositon to be "
                + String.valueOf(mListRowPosition));
        new AttemptGetCustomerInfo().execute();

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(service.getQuantity()));
        description.setText(service.getDescription());

        // Set up the listener for the delete button.

        final int pos = position;
        delete.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog("deleteButton", pos);
            }
        });

        customerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog("customerView", pos);
            }
        });

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }


class AttemptGetCustomerInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String shortname = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            DatabaseHelper db_helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = db_helper.getReadableDatabase();

            Log.d("AttemptGetCustomerInfo",
                    "ListRowPos: " + String.valueOf(mListRowPosition));
            Log.d("AttemptGetCustomerInfo", "description of ListRowPos: "
                    + services.get(mListRowPosition).getDescription());
            int customer_id = services.get(mListRowPosition).getCustomerID();
            Log.d("AttemptGetCustomerInfo",
                    "customer id: " + String.valueOf(customer_id));
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT " + CustomerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SHORTNAME + " FROM "
                            + CustomerEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                            + CustomerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CUSTOMER_ID + "="
                            + customer_id, null);
            Log.d("AttemptGetCustomerInfo",
                    "available cursor size" + String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                Log.d("AttemptGetCustomerInfo", "There are no Cursor entries!");
                return null;
            }
            c.moveToFirst();
            shortname = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(CustomerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SHORTNAME));

            db.close();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (shortname != null) {
                customerView.setText(shortname);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Additional info:**

I didn't paste all of the code and a lot of code refering happens inside the above code to which no code is there also. I hope the function of my methods not shown are understandable via the method name.

Answer (score 2):

So, lets begin.

If you want to display information from your database in your `Listview` I strongly recommend you using `CursorAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` it will work far faster than it is probably now.

About the `getView()` calling, that happens because of the way Android paint listviews, the first time Android will call `getView()` several times in order to display properly things, if you change for example your `ListView` height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` or viceversa you will notice that your `getView()` method will get called a different number of times.

---

Now about your code, you are not properly programming your `getView()` method. Inside the first part `if (convertView == null)` you should define your views using the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) which will improve your performance.

Another problem I find here is that  you are launching your `AsyncTask` everytime you your  `getView()` method is called, that will produce a problem with your `ListView` scrolling as it will prevent of going smoothly (In a tablet for example you will run like 40 or 50 asynctask one after another, and that is a heavy workload).

If you want to keep your current code which I would strongly discourage you to do it, you will need a way of controlling if the current row have been executed your `AsyncTask` code in order to not repeat that work.

Hope it helps

Comment: And what do you think of the overall problem solution? If I use the CursorAdapter I will solve my problem?

Comment: You will have a fair improvement

Comment: Thanks for the additional lines. I applied the ViewHolder pattern and also saved the LayoutInflater reference for future accesses. It seems to be some better performance, but it doesn't fix the problem of some TextViews being just empty and the other filled (with the wrong text). I am happy to change my code, but other than the changes you told me, I can't think of something different. I need to run the AsyncTask for every row. I thought this would be the best way, but it doesn't quite seem like that. Do you have further improvements in form of code (if possible)?

Comment: What if you run that query beforehand for every row you need and send it with your `Service` object? that would be faster

Comment: And another improvement: Close the cursor always after run your queries!, if not, you will produce a memory leak.